# htaccess redirect adds query and original URL to redirected page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've tried using each of the following

```
Redirect 301 /example http://website.com/new-page
RedirectMatch 301 /example(.*) /new-page/$1
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)$ http://website.com/new-page$1 [R=301,L]
```

In each case the final URL resolves to "website.com//new-page//?q=/example/"

Note that it is adding `/?q=/example/` to the final URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be due to other rules in your .htaccess. Use this rule to capture original string from `THE_REQUEST` variable. And add `?` in the end to strip off query string.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+example(\S*)\s [NC[
RewriteRule ^ http://website.com/new-page/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Brilliant! What about if the orignal url is /example/sub-folder/ ?